# What will be the best database structure in mysql to store approx 450 million rows of given data

Tags: mysql, database-schema

**Sample Data**

```
"Service_Area_Code" | "Phone_Numbers" | "Preferences"  | "Opstype" | "Phone_Type"
      13                9827259163           0               A           2
      13                9827961481           0               D           2
      11                9827202228           0               A           2
      2                 9827529897           0               D           2
      13                9827700249           0               A           2
```

**My Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `master` (
  `circle` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `phone` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `prefrences` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `ops_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `phone_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

- Is it a good database structure in my case?
- should i split this data into multiple tables or one table is enough to hold all data.
- My server configuration is 4GB Ram, 2GB Vswap, 4 Cores CPU and 125GB HDD, So by considering all above scenario, please suggest me the best way to deploy this database.

Comment: You should look into indexes.

Comment: I've seen MySQL tables bigger than 450M rows. Your main issue is going to be with updates/retrievals. Like ceejayoz says, you need to think about indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will the queries look like?  Need to see them to judge what `INDEXes` to include.

For 450M rows, it is important to shrink the datatypes as much as practical.

Are all text things ASCII?  If so `CHARACTER SET ascii`.  Then choose whether you want case folding:  `COLLATE ascii_general_ci` vs `ascii_bin`.

`varchar(1)` may as well be `CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' '` (or some other suitable default).

`bigint(10)` will allow 19 digits with an optional leading dash (minus).  Will you be filtering out dashes and parentheses?  (I hope so.)  Is this limited to the USA?  The `(10)` implies such.  In any case, `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `DECIMAL(10,0)` takes 5 bytes.  (11,0) also takes 5; 12 or 13 takes 6; etc.

`preferences` is show as a number `0`, yet defined as `VARCHAR`.  Decide on numeric or string, otherwise you could be in for some surprises.  Also consider the `SET` datatype, which would take only 2 bytes to specify any combination of 16 binary options.

Use `UNSIGNED` whenever practical.  (Example: `TINYINT UNSIGNED` gives you a range of 0-255.)

Do *not* split it into multiple tables.  That would be a coding headache with *no* performance benefit.  `PARTITIONing` is another form of splitting, but until we see the queries, I doubt if it would be of *any* benefit.

450M is not much different than 10M or 10B.  If you had a *trillion* rows, I would worry about the number of rows.

Your table will take about 20G-30GB after my suggestions and getting suitable indexes added on.  With `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M` (about right for your small 4GB machine), the table certainly will not be fully cacheable, and complex queries will need some careful attention.  (Again, we can't finish this question without seeing the queries.)

**How to Load**

Given that you have about 45 CSV files with 10M rows each, and the CSV files are not sorted, here is what I propose for reasonably high-speed loading:

```
CREATE TABLE master ( ... ) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- as already discussed
CREATE TABLE t ( ... ) ENGINE=MyISAM; -- Same columns, but no index, not even PK.
foreach CSV file, do 3 steps:
    LOAD DATA ... INTO t ... -- load one CSV file: a few minutes
    INSERT INTO master
        SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY phone;
    TRUNCATE TABLE t;        -- a few seconds
DROP TABLE t;  -- when finished.
```

If you need any processing of the data, it can be done inside or after the `LOAD DATA`.

The first few `INSERT..SELECTs` will be very fast because everything is cached.  By the last the CSV, that step will be noticeably slower.  But the overall speed may be acceptable.  I expect "a few days" to do it all.

Comment: Are you checking the existence of a given `phone`?  (That query does not seem to do anything else.)

Comment: The existing PK handles that; no extra `INDEXes` needed.

Comment: The typical such query (for a random phone) will involve 1 disk hit, so will typically take about 10ms if you have a traditional disk.  Unless there is some pattern to `phone`, you can sustain about 100 reads or writes per second.  It would take more than a month to fill up the 450M rows _if randomly_ inserted.

Comment: If the data comes in sorted by `phone`, it would probably take less than a day to load.

Comment: There is only one query which will be fired. `code` "SELECT phone from master where phone=*/any phone no/*"; `code`. We have only to check that a given phone is listed or not in database. The phone will be always 10 digit no without any dashes and parentheses, so DECIMAL(10,0) will be better. Preferences sometime contains "2#3#4#6#7"  so i have decided to choose varchar.

Comment: yes, i have to check only the existence of a phone no. I have alreday the data csv dump files. Each file have 10 million records.

Comment: It would help the load to sort them first, if they are not already in `phone` order.  If that is not practical, I can devise another technique.

Comment: phone is not sorted, and the range of phone will lies between 7000000000 to 9999999999. So is there any possible index apart from PK which will improve the performance.

Comment: How can i sort these files? Is there any way to sort by phone. Because the files are very large, aprox 350 MB, Another problem is if i sort each file separately, then the final database will not be sorted according to phone.

Comment: For that one `SELECT`, any index starting with `phone` is good.  `PRIMARY KEY(phone)` is very good.  Anything else is very, very, poor.

Comment: I added "How to load" to my Answer.

Comment: I estimate that `t` will be 170MB (about half the CSV).  The `ORDER BY` will sort the 10M rows; the `INSERT` will slip them in where they need to go.  Each iteration will involve one sweep over `master`, which will grow each time.